Getting cannot index into a null array even though each index in the array has a value
So I have an issue, the line 40 comparison always returns this error
Error
but as you can see from the code, I have prefilled $AuditResults with 0s as a way to ensure that the array is not null, this error happens from the very first run of the loop, and the array is larger than either of the imported sheets.
Import-Module -Name ImportExcel

$CurrentFOBDoc = Import-Excel "path\to\doc"

$CurrentElikaFOB = Import-CSV "path\to\doc"

$AuditResluts = [Object[]]::new(300)

$count = 0

foreach($value in $AuditResluts){
    $AuditResluts[$count] = 0
    $count++
}

$count = 0

foreach ($Fob in $CurrentFOBDoc){

    foreach ($EFob in $CurrentElikaFOB){
        IF($Fob.'Card Number' -like $EFob.'Wiegand 1 Code'){

            IF($Fob.'Facility Number' -like $EFob.'Facility 1 Code'){

                If(($Fob.'First Name' -like $EFob.'First Name' ) -and ($Fob.'Last Name' -like $EFob.'Last Name')){

                    $AuditResluts[$count] = "Fob $($Fob.'Facility Number') $($Fob.'Card Number') is assigned to $($Fob.'First Name')  $($Fob.'Last Name') in Elika and Log Sheet"
                                               
                }
                Else{
                    $AuditResults[$count] = "Fob $($Fob.'Facility Number') $($Fob.'Card Number') is not assigned to $($Fob.'First Name') $($Fob.'Last Name') in Elika, please reconcile"                  
                }
            }
        }
        
    }

    echo $AuditResluts[$count]

   #This Comparison gives the error, -eq gives the same result
    If($AuditResults[$count] -like 0){
        $AuditResults[$count] = "Fob $($Fob.'Facility Number') $($Fob.'Card Number') assigned to $($Fob.'First Name') $($Fob.'Last Name') Not found in Elika"
    }

    $count ++
}

each echo confirms there is a value present, and in Run and Debug I can see the values stored in the array, any help is greatly appreciated

Just use $count-1 | The first index is 0, not 1 in programming. Or $AuditResults.Count. Idk what do you want to do with the last “if”. | Actually “like” not equal with “eq”.

$count is 0 when the first value is added. the last if checks if the array was updated, all values in the array are set to 0, so if the fob isn't on both sheets it should write that message

Do you know that you have a typo? AuditResults vs AuditResluts. The second one is created and the first one is $null. Try to use VSCode.

I did not, my dyslexia strikes again, legit cannot see these mistakes unless someone points it out, that fixed it, thank you! And I do use VSCode, it did not point out the error though

Just try the VSCode, if you select a variable name, you can see where you used it and where you use another one with typo.

@AlexBoBalex See this for a how to make PS throw an error when using an undeclared variable: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/enforce-better-script-practices-by-using-set-strictmode/

You are probably getting a singleton instead of an array try :
$CurrentFOBDoc = @(Import-Excel "path\to\doc") and
$CurrentElikaFOB = @(Import-CSV "path\to\doc")
